# jsf Editable Dropdown

Tags: jsf

I am trying to use Editable drop-downs in my jsf application, Is there any way to do it? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

In JSF doesn't exist such a component. An alternative is to use Richfaces combobox to achieve editable dropdown.
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?c=comboBox

Answer (score 0):

There is an editable Dropdown (selectonemenu)
Please Refer: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf